# How are pairs serialized in Tezos?

Tags: michelson, serialization, pack

Running the `PACK` operation on a tuple (represented as a pair in Michelson, I get

```
$ ligo interpret -s pascaligo 'Bytes.pack((1, 2))'
0x05070700010002
```

The numbers 1 and 2 are serialized as `0001` and `0002`, respectively.

The tuple `(1,2)` is represented as `PAIR 1 2` in Michelson and `PAIR` serializes to `0x07`. So why are there two `0x07` values, and not just one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a break down:

- 05: all michelson values are tagged with the prefix `0x05` ([ref](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/blob/14db5279166aa14a590f4f92ee07aea81c2ea6a5/src/proto_alpha/lib_protocol/script_ir_translator.ml#L5732)).
- 07: the first tag denotes the micheline constructor. `Pair 1 2` is a primitive application with 2 arguments and no annotation. [The corresponding tag is 0x07.](https://gist.github.com/smondet/f5b785a6bbe6adb431fd7bca5e6df91a#file-pack-binary-schema-txt-L367)
- 07: the next tag denotes the michelson primitive. [It so happens that the corresponding tag is also 0x07](https://gist.github.com/smondet/f5b785a6bbe6adb431fd7bca5e6df91a#file-pack-binary-schema-txt-L28).
- 0001: encoding of the integer `1`
- 0002: encoding of the integer `2`

Let's try another example. What is the encoding of the value `Left 1` of type `or nat bool`? Per `tezos-client hash data 'Left 1' of type 'or nat bool'`, it will be `0x05 05 05 0001`, where:

- `05`: the fixed prefix denotes a michelson data value, as above.
- `05`: the expression `Left 1` is a primitive application with one argument and no annotations. The corresponding tag is also `0x05`.
- `05`: the michelson primitive is `Left`, for which the corresponding tag is also `05`.
- `0001`: encoding of the integer `1`.

Comment: OK, so `07` means both the `Pair` type constructor, and primitive. Got it. I would have though the first `07` was the primitive value and only the 2nd was the `Pair` type constructor, though.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last phrase: what do you mean with "primitive value"? and note that `Pair` is not a type constructor but a data constructor. However, `pair` is a type constructor (admittedly, it is confusing). Lowercase keywords are types, and capitalized keywords are data constructors. Example: `Pair` is a constructor that constructs values of type `pair x y`. `pair` is a type constructor with two arguments.